# Android studio NavigationDrawer sub items that change on runtime

Tags: android, submenu, android-menu, navigation-drawer

I really need your help on editing my navigation drawer. I want to add sub items to it as shown here: 
[image: example]

or here: 
[image: example2]

I have tried to search for similar questions on google but didn't find an answer. To me, its seems that possible solution may be to add a group of items after 3rd item and make this group invisible, but when the user clicks on "parent" it will become visible. However I am not sure how to insert group of items after specific index in menu and that may not be the best solution. 
So I am asking for experienced developers to help me find the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first approach, you can make a little edit. That SubItem is also an item an instead of putting everything in group you should put in an item. Try this example below:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_category_electronics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:title="Electronics">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_laptops"
                android:icon="@drawable/laptop"
                android:title="Laptops" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_tablet"
                android:icon="@drawable/tablet3"
                android:title="Tablets" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_phones"
                android:icon="@drawable/smartphone"
                android:title="Mobile Phones" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_gadgets"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_developer_mode_black_18dp"
                android:title="Gadgets" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion didn't help. Firstly, it doesn't add sub items to menu item. Secondly, I can't determine how many items I need in submenu, that need to be done at runtime (after parsing XML is done).

Answer (score 1):

You've probably found a solution by now, but let me chip this in any way. I cannot give you a quick fix for this, it's been a while since I wrote Android code, but I can point you in the right direction.

What you would want to do is to create a custom xml layout for the menu. You can then replace the Friends item with an expandable ListView. You'll then need an adapter to take the list of friends (probably in an ArrayList) and populate the expandable ListView. If you have ever populated a ListView with using an adapter, you will be able to figure this out.
Here's a [cool tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) you can adapt to get the job done.

I know it's a bit of work, and I wish I knew an easier way to do it, but I don't. All the best. Cheers!

Comment: You are right, I no longer need this (decided to implement it another way) but thanks for your efforts and suggestion, I appreciate it.